# Can the port of a UML component only be a singleton?

Tags: uml, singleton, component

I am working on a  software assignment where the design is component based. The components have ports which provide interfaces.

My professor argues that the Port class which is exposed by each component should be a Singleton, as the port must be the only way to interact with the component. As I see it, multiple instances don't interfere with the requirement that the port must be the single interaction point.

Is as singleton the right way to implement a Port to the component?

To give an example:
The assignment is a model of an airplane and an airport. The components are different parts of an airplane and the airport. As it is a group assignment, different students have to implement different components.
This is the UML diagram of the different components of the airport: [image: Airport Components]

The interfaces are implemented in a class named Port, which is an inner class to the actual implementation. The outer class has a public field port and is a singleton. The different components interact by loading the Jar-File and accessing the Port instance via reflection.

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "port"? A component is defined by the interface(s) that it provides to the public (to other components) and by interfaces that it requires from components that it interacts with. These interfaces could be any form of API - RESTful APIs, XML exchanges over a service bus, database schemas, methods on one or more classes.

Comment: I would think that an single interface is all that is required.  Whether the implementation of the interface is shared is irrelevant.  Unless you are working within the constraints of a much more limited component system, the singleton requirement is only a constraint imposed by your professor.  My suggestion?  Comply with what your professor asked you to do for the assignment, learn what you can learn, but keep an open mind in the future.

Comment: What if you have two of the same kind of component?

Comment: You might want to include en example diagram as reference: https://www.uml-diagrams.org/component-diagrams.html

Comment: @ErikEidt, Really depends on what the component does.  In most real-world cases, it doesn't (and shouldn't) matter which instance you use.  That's how the cloud can spin up resources to handle surge traffic.  Multiple instances of the same service spun up to distribute load.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch, right, so are you answering the question that a singleton for the Port is ok or not ok?

Comment: @ErikEidt, correct.  It's a tangential concern, and there are mechanisms that exist to handle multiple instances of it.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch, sorry, multiple instances of a Singleton?

Comment: @ErikEidt, See my answer.  And the singleton is a red-herring.  I think it may be a case of bad terminology since the GoF defined what a Singleton is in the case of OOP, which I don't think means the same thing in the case of UML.

Comment: My professor argues that there can't be more than one instance of a port, and therefore must be implemented as a GoF singleton

Comment: @patrick246, as I mentioned before, you'll have to do your assignment the way your professor outlined it.  Doesn't mean you can't keep your mind open for the future.

Comment: My professor is open for suggestions, he's doing the assignment for the first time, so while I probably won't benefit from any improvements to it, the assignment may change for future years. I was asking this question because I only have basic knowledge on UML, but it didn't seem right to only allow one instance and having to access the component by reflection

Comment: You could have multiple ports but surely each one would be a separate instance. It makes sense to make each specific port type a singleton, to keep it simple as a basic implementation strategy. I assume you're coding this from the ground up in Java without using any libraries?

Answer (score 4):

> Can the port of a UML component only be a singleton?

According to https://www.uml-diagrams.org/port.html UML does have notation to indicate **multiple instances** of a port, as well as **multiple interfaces** to a port.

> Multiplicity of a port (if any) is shown after the port name in square brackets. Both name and multiplicity of port are optional.
>
> [image: UML Port with multiplicity - Library Services class has 1 to 6 searchPort ports.]
>
> *Library Services class has 1 to 6 searchPort ports.*

In UML diagrams, you will most likely see the majority of diagrams with one port.  From a *logical* perspective, this is correct.  From an *implementation* perspective, it shouldn't matter.

Logically, you are connecting to one instance of a component that exposes functionality on the port.  In real life there may be multiple instances of the same component and you only care about the interaction with one of them.

Comment: What you mean in the last sentence, is that there is one port for each instance, isn't it ?

Comment: The multiplicity of ports in the diagram is _per instance_ of the component.  They are not, to my knowledge, global constraints.

Comment: yes, I fully agree ! This is the right answer ! An uml port is not necessarily an ip port, nor a service queue.

Comment: In the example with Library search, it's not 100% certain *why* there are 6 ports, but we can assume it's for availability. Does the client accessing the service have to address it as `searchPort[1]` or `searchPort[2]`, or does the `LibraryServices` balance the access? In UML it seems outside elements are aware of these names and would be the ones to decide. Six named instances (using their array index) is not very different from six different ports. Gotta love UML for generating heat.

Answer (score 1):

## Singelton as a concept

Yes, since the port is a *limited resource* there should be only one object at runtime (a singleton) interacting with it. It should handle concurrent access of other components to that port.

So your application should create only one instance of the "PortHandler".

## Singelton as Code pattern

Often the *logical singelton* as described above is realized in code using the *Singelton Pattern*  (`private` constructor and `static` accessor method)

This should be avoided.

The reason is that this *static access* makes your code *tight coupled* and therefore hard to reuse and in consequence hard to test. Also this "code supported singeltons" are merely a *global variables* which are known being evil almost since the beginning of programming...

e.g.: if you want to *unittest* your code interacting with the "PortHandler" you might want to replace the real  "PortHandler" with a *test double* which you can programmatically configure to produce well defined data for your tested code.

If your Code under test gets the  "PortHandler" via the static accessor method of the *Singelton Pattern* it is hard to replace.

If you pass the "PortHandler" in via *dependency injection* (using a DI framework by any chance) replacing it for testing is easy...